# How to Return view from a string in MVC3 in C#

Tags: razor, view

```
public ActionResult Default()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Hello,World!";
    var template = "<h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>";
    //How to make the content of the following "View" = "template"
    return View();
}
```

Then build html result as:

```
<h1>Hello,World!</h1>
```

Plase help me,Thanks! I know RazorEngine can parse Razor file,but can't Render string to View.

Comment: Why? Why not simply use a proper view? What problem is this solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the content result instead, which returns the raw content.  It does not use an associated view, but only returns content directly to the requestor.

```
return Content(template);
```

Comment: your result is:<h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>

Comment: Yes, true.  Didn't see the "@".  Is it possible to do: `return Content("<h1>" + ViewBag.Message.ToString() + "</h1>");`